# How do push back button to previous step ? - Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have 3 page is "Home,Navigation,Info".

Now.When I push button from home It navigation to "Navigation".And When I push button from Navigation It navigation to "Info".But When I push back button it navigation to "home".

I want to navigation previous step ("Navigation").

Here my code in Main.js of controller:

```
Ext.define('Catalog.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs: {
            homepanel: 'homepanel',
            navigation: 'navigation',
            info: 'info'

        },
        control: {
            homepanel: {
                back: 'backButtonHandler'
            },
            navigation:{
                back: 'backButtonNav'
            },
            info:{
                back: 'backFromNav'
            }
        }
    },
    backButtonHandler: function(button){
        console.log("OK backButtonHandler");
        Ext.getCmp('category').show();  
    },
    backButtonNav: function(button){
        console.log("OK backButtonNav"); 
    },
    backFromNav: function(button){
        console.log("OK backFromNav"); 
    }
});
```

How do I do ? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [navigation view](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View). Its simply a stack of view that handles automatically the back button.
You can push and pop views using:

> navigationView.push({xtype:'viewToPush'});
>
> navigationView.pop();
>    navigationView.pop(5); // pop 5 views, like press 5 times back button

[Here a live example](http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.0/docs/Ext.navigation.View.1/viewer.html)